# Random Fetch Error when I restart my program

Tags: node.js, express

I'm looping through this array of names and using each name to change the end point in the URI. The data from the end points is then stored in a Promise.all() array. I then run the array through a for loop and outputs the data into an EJS file. This works sometimes. However sometimes the console logs the error at the bottom of this post. When I increase the amount of endpoints i'm requesting this error happens everytime. The error appears to be very random and the error stops at random endpoints. I'm assuming i'm maybe sending to many requests? I eventually want to loop through around 5000 endpoints in this code but i'm struggling just loop through 20. Any help is much appreciated.

````
  body: new URLSearchParams({ grant_type: 'client_credentials' }),
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(appId + ':' + appSecret).toString('base64')
  }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(token2 => secondtoken(token2))

function secondtoken(token2){
let accesstoken = token2.access_token; 
const promises = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 20;i++){
promises.push(fetch('https://us.api.blizzard.com/profile/wow/character/'+ slug[i]+'/'+ lowercasenames[i] +'?namespace=profile-us&locale=en_US', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accesstoken}`
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json()))

}
  Promise.all(promises)
  .then(data => { profiledata(data)})

};
  
function profiledata(data){
  const name = []
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length;i++){
  name.push(data[i].name)
};

console.log(name)
  res.render('index', {
    leaderboard: diomerda,
    rank: rank,
    rating: rating,
    slug: slug,
    faction: faction,
    statsplayed: statsplayed,
    statswon: statswon,
    statslost: statslost,
    race: racename,
    name: name,
   })
  }}});```

The error is below:

D:\Coding\Form 1\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1461
                        reject(new FetchError(`request to ${request.url} failed, reason: ${err.message}`, 'system', err));
                               ^
FetchError: request to https://us.api.blizzard.com/profile/wow/character/area-52/toonah?namespace=profile-us&locale=en_US failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\Coding\Form 1\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1461:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
````

Comment: Connection reset... interesting. That sounds slightly confusing, but I'd guess it's some rate limiting by that API you use.